# Linq to SQL Group by and Sum in Select

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I need to convert that SQL Query into Linq:

```
SELECT
    SUM([ArticleAmount]) as amount
    ,[ArticleName]
FROM [DB].[dbo].[OrderedArticle]

group by articlename

order by amount desc
```

I tried the following code but I get an error at "a.ArticleName" that says a definition of "ArticleName" would be missing.

```
var sells = orderedArt
            .GroupBy(a => a.ArticleName)
            .Select(a => new {Amount = a.Sum(b => b.ArticleAmount),Name=a.ArticleName})
            .OrderByDescending(a=>a.Amount)
            .ToList();
```

Has someone of you and idea how to fix this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is `ArticleName` a column in `orderedArt`? I'd download [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/). It can convert from SQL to Linq so you can put the query into that and pull out the correct Linq code.

Comment: Yes, ArticleName is a column in orderedArt.
The error only occurs in the select. The GroupBy works.
I'll try LINQPad, thanks for the tip :)

Comment: I'd give LINQPad a try. It should at least point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are getting this error because the Grouping doesn't return `IEnumerable<OrderedArticle>` but `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, OrderedArticle>>`

You need to change your code to use `a.Key`:

```
var sells = orderedArt
    .GroupBy(a => a.ArticleName)
    .Select(a => new { Amount = a.Sum(b => b.ArticleAmount), Name = a.Key})
    .OrderByDescending(a => a.Amount)
    .ToList();
```