# How can I sum() calculated fields in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have this example model:

```
namespace Facturacion.Models
{
    public class Test
    {
        public int testId { get; set; }    

        [Required]
        public decimal price { get; set; }

        public decimal calculated
        {
            get
            {
                return (decimal)(price*2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I need the sum() of the calculated field, but sum() only appears to work for stored values and my calculated field does not appear in the database table.

How can I retrieve the sum as a column in my enumerable?

**Edit:**

Actually, my real model is a little more complex. This is the query I'm trying:

```
var items = db.myTable.Where(c => c.aField == factura.aField);
ViewBag.items = items.ToList();

var grupo = from c in items
    group c by c.tax into g
    select new { accumulatedTax = g.Sum(s => s.taxAmmount) };
```

I already tried the solution of this other question [Linq to SQL Group by and Sum in Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13988800/linq-to-sql-group-by-and-sum-in-select), but it only works with non calculated fields.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean when you say that sum is not working?  I just did `var test1 = new Test { testId = 1, price = 2.99M };
            var test2 = new Test{testId = 2, price = 5.25M};

            List<Test> list = new List<Test>() { test1, test2 };

            var theSum = list.Sum(x => x.calculated);` and theSum was correct.

Comment: I am trying to get the result in a column of an Enumerable, because I want to group some of the values before displaying them in a table.

Comment: In your example, is taxAmount the computed field?  If so, try doing the calculation in the query, such as    `g.Sum(s => s.taxAmount * 2)` or something.  Does that work?

Comment: It won't work because the filed is a calculated one. I think I'll store the value in the database

Comment: Linq to SQL will cause a SQL query to be executed against database. Instead, do a items.ToList() and do the Sum() against the entities. (Linq to entities).